Dirty bits for types that span less than 256 bits in Solidity
The solidity language documentation for "inline assembly" explicitly does not give any guarantees about bits that do not take part in a variable's Type's encoding:
"If you access variables of a type that spans less than 256 bits (for example uint64, address, or bytes16), you cannot make any assumptions about bits not part of the encoding of the type. Especially, do not assume them to be zero. To be safe, always clear the data properly before you use it in a context where this is important: uint32 x = f(); assembly { x := and(x, 0xffffffff) / now use x / } To clean signed types, you can use the signextend opcode: assembly { signextend(<num_bytes_of_x_minus_one>, x) }"
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.26/assembly.html#access-to-external-variables-functions-and-libraries
Is this also the case for constants? In other words, if we define a constant:
"uint16 constant amount = 392;"
and later access it, can we rely on the fact that no dirty bits are added?
For context, let's assume that a developer defines several constants of type "uint16" that have been imported and used throughout the codebase.
The developer cannot afford to use the type "uint256" for these constants because there are many of them and it would blow up the smart contract's bytecode size.
The developer cannot afford to clean up the most significant 240 bits of each constant every time that they are used because it would incur significant gas cost.
In such a scenario, can the developer reliably access the "uint16" constant without worrying about dirty bits?
I understand that we cannot predict what the future versions of Solidity will be like, but could there be any issues in the current version?
We did not face any issue (i.e., we did not get any dirty bits) while simulated with Hardhat using Solidity 0.8.27. But we are still worried about potential issues.

If it's a constant, depending on the use case, I would assume Solidity generates PUSHx/POPx instructions and it could not be dirty. Because constants are not comingled with variables in storage, I cannot see how they would be dirty, if I understood the question correctly.
